# VBA - Pulling averages for rows in a dynamic group of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this spread sheet of data where it pulls daily information for different securities going back a year. I have a row (row three) where I use VBA to pull in all the weekdays from a year from the today() function. These start in C3 and go horizontally. The data I am looking at starts in C4 and spans the ~100 rows I have and all the dates so ~260 columns.

I am trying to pull the 3mo, 6mo and 12mo averages and standard deviations of this this data and place them all in their own respective columns at the end of the data set. So it would add 6 columns.

Since the number of columns for the dates and the data points I need for the rows can change by a couple each time I need to figure this out dynamically. I was able to use the below to get the range filled with the equation I need but cant figure it for the above.

```
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    LastCol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("C4", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).FormulaR1C1 = Range("C4").FormulaR1C1
'Next
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is.

Comment: There's different solution to your problem. One could be to use the weekday function and then you might need smaller adjustment. My personal solution is using a dummy table where all the calendar dates (US and local) are stored (until many years in the future). Then I do a lookup to that table and check if the date is a workday or not. I can then filter on the last 3 mo or last 6 mo or a specific period and I always know that the dates in scope is always relevant. Calendar/Holiday's is a bit of (manual) headache when it comes to financial instruments ;/.

Answer (score 0):

So, after you get your data settled into its place, save the the number of columns that were written into:
`LastDataCol = <worksheet>.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Then start to write the headers and formulas for the six averages. I am assuming here you can manage the actual formulas to calculate the averages with their variable number of days (columns):

```
<worksheet>.Cells(3,LastDataCol+1).Value="Qtr1 Avg"
<worksheet>.Cells(4,LastDataCol+1).Formula = <myformula for 1st qtr average>
<worksheet>.Cells(3,LastDataCol+2).Value="Qtr2 Avg"
<worksheet>.Cells(4,LastDataCol+2).Formula = <myformula for 2nd qtr average>
   ...  etc  ...
```

Finally, extend the formulas down with range.FillDown,

```
<worksheet>.Range(Cells(4,LastDataCol+1),Cells(<worksheet>.UsedRange.Rows.Count, LastDataCol+6)).FillDown
```

That should do it.